# ternary operator do nothing in else part

Tags: java

I have tried to leave the else part empty for ternary operator ( for int variables ), but I can't do it what is the problem?

here is the code

```
int FemaleCounter=0, MaleCounter =0, StateCounterIn =0 , StateCounterOut =0;

if(arr[0].equals("male") ) {
    MaleCounter ++;
}
if(arr[0].equals("female") ) {
    FemaleCounter ++;
}
if(arr[1].equals("in")) {
    StateCounterIn++;                   
}
if(arr[1].equals("out") ) {
    StateCounterOut++;
}
```

here is the ternary operator form :-

```
MaleCounter = arr[0].equals("male") ? MaleCounter++ : ;
FemaleCounter = arr[0].equals("female") ? FemaleCounter++ : ;
StateCounterIn = arr[1].equals("in") ? StateCounterIn++ : ;
StateCounterOut = arr[1].equals("out") ? StateCounterOut++ : ;
```

Thanks for your answers .

Comment: MaleCounter = arr[0].equals("male") ? MaleCounter++ : MaleCounter;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
        MaleCounter += arr[0].equals("male") ? 1 : 0;
        FemaleCounter += arr[0].equals("female") ? 1 : 0;
        StateCounterIn += arr[1].equals("in") ? 1 : 0;
        StateCounterOut += arr[1].equals("out") ? 1 : 0;
```

A ternary expression must deliver a result. Also ++ inside and then assigment is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

As its name indicates, the ternary operator takes three operands.  You cannot omit any of them any more than you can omit either operand of any of the binary operators (`*`, `/`, `.`, *etc*.), or the one operand of a unary operator (`++`, `--`, among others).

The fact that an expression using the ternary operator is in some ways analogous to an `if` / `then` / `else` statement is irrelevant here, but the key distinction is important: an expression in the ternary operator evaluates to a value.  It is necessary to designate that value for each alternative.

Observe, further, that your analogy is false anyway.  You might consider fixing the syntax issue by using forms similar to this ...

```
       // useless
       MaleCounter = arr[0].equals("male") ? MaleCounter++ : MaleCounter;
```

..., but that does not have the same effect as your corresponding `if` statement, because in the case where the increment is performed, the pre-increment value is afterward assigned back to `MaleCounter`.

I find your original code pretty clear, but if for some reason you insist on using the ternary operator, then one of these is the model I would follow:

```
       MaleCounter = arr[0].equals("male") ? MaleCounter + 1 : MaleCounter;

       FemaleCounter += (arr[0].equals("female") ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: The mention that the original `if` is pretty clear; does just what is needed, makes this a worthy answer.